# Is this right logic flow of Variational Autoencoder?

Tags: deep-learning, statistical-ai, variational-inference

### Object Function

$$
maximize = \Pi_d^D P(X_d) = \Pi_d^D \sum_i^N P(X_d,Z_i)
$$

D : # of data

N : # of latent variable state

$$
NLL = - \sum_d^D \log \sum_i^N P(X_d,Z_i) = - \sum_d^D \log \sum_i^N P(X_d,Z_i) \frac{Q(Z_i|X_d)}{Q(Z_i|X_d)}
$$

#### Jensen's Inequality

$$
\leq  - \sum_d^D  \sum_i^N Q(Z_i|X_d) \log \frac{P(X_d,Z_i) }{Q(Z_i|X_d)}
$$

$$
=  - \sum_d^D  \sum_i^N Q(Z_i|X_d) \log \frac{P(X_d|Z_i) P(Z_i) }{Q(Z_i|X_d)}
$$

$$
=  \sum_d^D [ D_{KL}(Q(Z_i|X_d)|| P(Z_i)) - \sum_i^N Q(Z_i|X_d) \log P(X_d|Z_i) ]
$$

$$
=  \sum_d^D  D_{KL}(Q(Z_i|X_d)|| P(Z_i)) - E_Z[\log P(X_d|Z_i)] 
$$

## KL- divergence term (Regularizer)

$Z_i$ is continous, so we assume Z as Gaussain.

$$
D_{KL}(Q(Z_i|X_d)|| P(Z_i)) =  -\int_{Z_i} Q(Z_i|X_d) \log P(Z_i)) + \int_{Z_i} Q(Z_i|X_d) \log [Q(Z_i|X_d) ]
$$

#### multivariate Gaussian Distribution

if basis is appropriately adjusted, then we can assume that sigma is diagonal matrix which means that offdiagonal term is 0. so covariance matrix $\sum$ is written as $\sigma^2I$

$$
Q(Z|X) \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2I)
$$

$$
D_{KL} = (\mu^2 + \sigma^2 -1)/2 - \log \sigma
$$

Q() can be reparameterize to differentiable, determistic variable

$$
P(Z_i) \sim N(0,I) \\
Z_i \sim Q(Z_i|X_d) = Q_\phi (\epsilon,X_d) \\
\epsilon \sim p(\epsilon) \\
$$

applying amortized inference Q

$$
Q(Z_i|X_d;\phi)  = \Pi_i Q(Z_i;NN_i(X_d;\phi_i))
$$

#### Reparameterization Trick

$$
Q_\phi (\epsilon,X_k) = \mu + \epsilon * \sigma
$$

#### Monte-carlo sampling

where $\epsilon^{(d)} \sim p(\epsilon)$

$$\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I)$$.

## Expectation term (Reconstruction)

$E_i^{(d)}$ is reconstructed data and $E_i$ is original data

Depending upon the assumption of $E_i$ and $p_\theta\left(E \mid E^{(d)}\right)$

If $E_i$ is continuous and $p_\theta\left(E_i \mid E_i^{(d)}\right) \sim \mathrm{N}\left(E_i^{(d)}, 1^2\right)$
$$
\log p_\theta\left(E \mid E^{(d)}\right)=C \times \log \exp \left(-\frac{\left(E_i-E_i^{(d)}\right)^2}{2}\right)=-C \times\left(E_i-E_i^{(d)}\right)^2
$$
$\cdot$ If $E_i$ is discrete and $p_\theta\left(E_i \mid E_i^{(d)}\right) \sim \operatorname{Bern}\left(E_i^{(d)}\right)$

$$
\log p_{\theta}(E \mid E^{(d)})
$$

$$
=\log E^{(d)^{K_i}}(1-E^{(d)})^{1-E_i}
$$

$$
=E_i \log E^{(d)}+(1-E_i) \log (1-E^{(d)}
$$

is this right logic flow?
please let me know about this.
thanks to read :D

Comment: what you called amortized inference is actually Amortized inference + mean field assumption... but the rest I would say that is correct, however, I would say that this only explains the math, not the intuition (though this might be a personal take)